# Reads with validation for email or empty string in Play/Scala

Tags: json, scala, validation, playframework

I am trying to create a validator for reads that will only allow a valid email or an empty string.

What I tried until now seem to work only partially.
Here is my reads defenition:

```
case class EmailFieldValueForm(value: String) extends FieldValueForm

val emailFieldValueFormReads: Reads[EmailFieldValueForm] =
    (__ \ "value").read[String](email or maxLength(0)).map(EmailFieldValueForm.apply _)
```

When I test it, I am getting the following error:

> diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Reads[V]
>   [error] starting with value uuidReads in trait DefaultReads [error]
>   (__ \ "value").read[String](email or
>   maxLength(0)).map(EmailFieldValueForm.apply _)

Also, tried doing it with regex:

```
val emailFieldValueFormReads: Reads[EmailFieldValueForm] =
    (__ \ "value").read[String](email or pattern("""^$"""r)).map(EmailFieldValueForm.apply)
```

And in this case, any json I provide is passing.For example:

```
val invalidJson = Json.parse(
        """
          |{
          | "value": "boo"
          |}
        """.stripMargin
```

Simply gives me an empty value, but does not fail validation.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

**SOLUTION**
Seems like I was not doing the testing correctly. The following worked:

```
val invalidJson = Json.parse(
        """
          |{
          | "value": "boo"
          |}
        """.stripMargin
      )

      (EmailFieldValueForm.emailFieldValueFormReads reads invalidJson match {
        case JsSuccess(value, _) => value
        case JsError(e) => throw JsResultException(e)
      }) must throwA[JsResultException]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in `implicit reads: Reads[M]` for `def maxLength[M](m: Int)(implicit reads: Reads[M], p: M => scala.collection.TraversableLike[_, M])`

You may specify type `M` explicitly and all will be fine

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.json._

val emailFieldValueFormReads: Reads[EmailFieldValueForm] =
  ((__ \ "value").read[String](email or maxLength[String](0))).map(EmailFieldValueForm.apply _)

Json.parse("""{"value": "sss"}""").validate[EmailFieldValueForm](emailFieldValueFormReads)
Json.parse("""{"value": ""}""").validate[EmailFieldValueForm](emailFieldValueFormReads)
Json.parse("""{"value": "a@a.com"}""").validate[EmailFieldValueForm](emailFieldValueFormReads)

scala> res0: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[EmailFieldValueForm] = JsError(List((/value,List(ValidationError(List(error.email),WrappedArray()), ValidationError(List(error.maxLength),WrappedArray(0))))))

scala> res1: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[EmailFieldValueForm] = JsSuccess(EmailFieldValueForm(),/value)

scala> res2: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[EmailFieldValueForm] = JsSuccess(EmailFieldValueForm(a@a.com),/value)
```

For testing with scalatest (PlaySpec) you may use

```
Json.parse("""{"value": "sss"}""").validate[EmailFieldValueForm](emailFieldValueFormReads) must be an 'error
Json.parse("""{"value": "a@a.com"}""").validate[EmailFieldValueForm](emailFieldValueFormReads) must be an 'success
Json.parse("""{"value": ""}""").validate[EmailFieldValueForm](emailFieldValueFormReads) must be an 'success
```

Comment: So, if I am doing through validate method it works. But, is't simple reads suppose to validate as well? Wee an update on the post.

Comment: When I was updating the post I realized that my tests are not setup correctly. See update.